# How to remove tool tip from summernote

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I'm trying to create a [summernote](http://summernote.org/) v0.8.1 with only one button in the toolbar, unordered list. I'm looking disable the tooltip that appears for the button. How do I go about doing that?

Here is an example of the [summernote](https://jsfiddle.net/ccakn5870/db5tk0cL/9/):

```
<div id="myNote"></div>
```

Initalize summernote

```
$("#myNote").summernote({
    toolbar: [
        ['para', ['ul']] // I want to disable the tooltip for this.
    ],
    focus: true
});
```

The html of the rendered button looks like this, in which the text of the actual tooltip is *"Unordered list (Ctrl+Shift+8)"*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-small" title=""
    data-shortcut="Ctrl+Shift+8" data-mac-shortcut="⌘+⇧+7" 
    data-event="insertUnorderedList" tabindex="-1" 
    data-original-title="Unordered list (Ctrl+Shift+8)">
        <i class="fa fa-list-ul icon-list-ul"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I it worked when I did this:

```
$("#myNote").summernote({
            toolbar: [
                ['para', ['ul']]
            ],
            focus: true
        });
$('.note-editor [data-event="insertUnorderedList"]').tooltip('disable');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
 $("#myNote").summernote({
            toolbar: [
                ['para', ['ul']]
            ],
            focus: true,
            onInit : function(){
                $('.note-editor [data-name="ul"]').tooltip('disable'); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've added the rendered HTML of the button(see original post). Is there a way using jQuery to remove the tooltip like you have it?

Comment: I have tried on your jsfiddle and it works. Maybe, try this `$('.note-editor [data-event="insertUnorderedList"]').tooltip('disable');` instead of `$('.note-editor [data-name="ul"]').tooltip('disable');`

Comment: I don't know why but I tried placing the same jQuery outside of the initialization of the summernote and it worked! Thanks for your help.